# Cross-platform object-oriented tools for mobile game development

Tags: oop, mobile, cross-platform

can anyone suggest any tools for 2d mobile game development? I'm interested in tools that use object oriented languages.

Comment: There are tons of options regarding 2d mobile game dev. Some of them you have to pay, others are free. All of them have some limitations, strong points, weaks points. Plus, it is a very dynamic field, so changes and new versions/alternatives happen. To narrow it a bit will be nice if you provide further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools for creating 2D games. I would consider unity 3D. You can find more detailed discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584717/2d-cross-platform-game-development-engines).