# LibGdx vs Citrus Engine

Tags: libgdx, citrus-engine

I saw this thread comment on 2D engines at [stackoverflow]:[2D Cross-Platform Game Development Engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584717/2d-cross-platform-game-development-engines)

I am interested in LibGdx (Java) and Citrus Engine(Action Script). What would you choose?

Comment: I am only asking for a recommendation and there exists guys that are judging you and can up and down your points.... thank for the one who answer me, because i won a contest and I am travelling to USA!

Answer (score 3):

I can only talk for LibGDX, but I can honestly say that it is the best game engine I've used so far. Let it be features, ease of use, or active community, LibGDX has it all.

It supports a lot of platforms, like Desktop, iOS, Android and others. It's really fast and supports both 2D and 3D as well as sound and physics engines which are included (Box2D and bullet physics).

There are tools like a particle editor, loaders for several map editors and UI skins. Join the official channel [#libgdx on freenode (IRC)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/community.html) if you have any questions and have a look at this [trend](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=libgdx).