# 2D cross-platform game engine

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, 2d, game-engine

I would like to create a 2D mobile game that could run on all devices (ios, android and windows phone).
For doing this I thought to use a game-engine but it seems to me like I am cheating. Is honest, for a programmer, use a game-engine? If yes, which one you advise to me?

Comment: It's totally normal to use a game engine to develop games. I would advise you Unity, among others ( I know it; it's complete and pretty easy to use ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2D Cross-Platform Game Development Engines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584717/2d-cross-platform-game-development-engines)

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages of game engine :**

- Most if not all of the coding is done for you, so all you have to worry about is content, level layout, etc.
- Along those lines, memory management, asset loading, lighting (in complex engines), etc has all been designed and tested thoroughly (hopefully).
- As mentioned below, if the engine is cross platform you will have to do little to no work to port your game.
- Built In Physics (2d or 3d)
- Rendering on a stable framerate
- Resource management (images, sound, data files)
- Better User interface

I **Suggest** you to use [Unity Game Engine](http://unity3d.com)

It is Very Easy to learn

It support 22 Platform with same code or little change and the platforms are [here](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform)

Answer (score 0):

Cheating? Not at all

Many games are made with games engines. You will always get best results if you use game engines.

In terms of which ones are good, I would recommend GameMaker:studio.
You can create games for many platforms including the ones you mentioned. There are also many tutorials online and on YouTube and it is so easy to learn.
Unity is a good engine however I don't really like it because the game engine is not exactly light weight and exports are not light weight either (My game was almost a gigabyte once and it didn't even have anything!)